# About Path normalize() in Java

Tags: java

For the following code, the aPath turns out to be **D:\ OCPJP7\ NIO2\ src\SubPath.java.** Why is the **programs** element gone?

```
Path aPath = Paths.get(" D:\\ OCPJP7\\ programs\\..\\ NIO2\\ src\\.\\ SubPath.java"); 
aPath = aPath.normalize();
```

Comment: Because `..` means parent directory, so the path goes into programs and then again back. A perfect case for `normalize`. The same for `.` the current directory itself.

Comment: Related questions point to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#normalize--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the normalization replaced the `..` `programs`' **parent** directory.

So you have `NIO2` as a sub-folder of `OCPJP7`.

Similarly, `.` goes away as it's redundant (indicates current directory within context).

Answer (score 1):

Because the **programs** element is followed by `\\..\\` which means "to go up one directory level". This sequence removes the `\\programs\\` part from your path.